# Provisioning api using java

Tags: java, api, provisioning

Hi i tried to retrieve all users from the domain using provisioning api & 2-legged OAuth in java program but it returns unknown authorization header........... when i started to search about it i got the scope as https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/#readonly. i dont what  what  #readonly  refers please explain it ....

Regards
Sharun

Comment: possible duplicate of [Provisioning Api using java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2880207/provisioning-api-using-java) (same user, a few hours earlier)

Comment: ya i tried with provisioning api.... ITS returning Unknown authorisation Header Error